# How do I connect to a websocket running on an EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, websocket, network-programming

I am running the webserver in Go on an EC2:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin:     func(r *http.Request) bool { return true },
}

func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    for {
        msgType, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        conn.WriteMessage(msgType, msg)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("listening")
    http.HandleFunc("/echo", echo)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8918", nil)
}
```

And sending a request to it using a Python script:

```
import websocket

ws = websocket.WebSocket()

ws.connect("ws://myEIP:8918/echo") // redacted elastic IP
ws.send("Hello, WebSocket!")

ws.close()
```

However this blocks for ~30 seconds before raising an exception:

```
Exception has occurred: TimeoutError
[Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

I have my NACL set up to allow everything on port 8918, on both inbound at outbound.

I have the security group set up to allow everything on port 8918 - also outbound, but I believe security group access is stateful, so outbound isn't necessary.

[image: security group]